# Error on Spring boot MySql application starting on Eclipse

Tags: mysql, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I am getting the below error on starting Spring-Boot app with MySQL DB on Eclipse.

```
main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 6, SQLState: HY000
ERROR 2020 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
Error on delete of 'C:\Windows\TEMP2\#sqlc5c_db_b.MYI' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

But I logged in as Admin user in my Windows machine. It was working fine early. But suddenly getting this error. Still it works sometimes.

Comment: You may be logged in as Admin user, but are you running said process AS an administrator?

Comment: Launch command prompt or service in admin mode